# DB design for one-to-one single column table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm unsure the best route to take for this example:

A table that holds information for a job; salary, dates of employment etc. The field I am wondering how best to store is 'job_title'.

- Job title is going to be used as part of an auto-complete field so
  I'll be using a query to fetch results.
- The same job title will be used by multiple jobs in the DB.
- Job title is going to be a large part of many queries in the
  application.
- A single job only ever has one title.

1 . Should I have a 2 tables, job and job_title, job table referencing the job_title table for its name.

2 . Should I have a 2 tables, job and job_title but store title as a direct value in job, job_title just storing a list of all preexisting values (somewhat redundant)?

3 . Or should I not use a reference table at all / other suggestion.

What is your choice of design in this situation, and how would it change in a one to many design?

This is an example, the actual design is much larger however I think this well conveys the issue.

**Update, To clarify:**

A User (outside scope of question) has many Jobs, a job (start/end date, {job title}) has a title, title ( name (ie. 'Web Developer' )

Comment: I would probably use a `job_title` table with auto_increment keys. Then i would have a `label` column for the human readable name and an additional `UNIQUE KEY` for a machine name (lets call that column `name`)... For example if the title is "Creative Director" then `label='Creative Director'` and `name='creative_director'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option 1 is the best design choice. Create the two tables along these lines:

- jobs (job_id PK, title_id FK not null, start_date, end_date, ...)
- job_titles (title_id PK, title)

The PKs should have clustered indexes; jobs.title_id and job_titles should have nonclustered or secondary indexes; job_titles.title should have a unique constraint.

This relationship can be modeled as 1-to-1 or 1-to-many (one title, many jobs). To enforce 1-to-1 modeling, apply a unique constraint to jobs.title_id. However, you should *not* model this as a 1-to-1 relationship, because it's not. You even say so yourself: "The same job title will be used by multiple jobs in the DB" and "A single job only ever has one title." An entry in the jobs table represents *a certain position held by a certain user during a certain period of time*. Because this is a 1-to-many relationship, a separate table is the correct way to model the data.

Here's a simple example of why this is so. Your company only has one CEO, but what happens if the current one steps down and the board appoints a new one? You'll have two entries in jobs which both reference the same title, even though there's only one CEO "position" and the two users' job date ranges don't overlap. If you enforce a 1-to-1 relationship, modeling this data is impossible.

Why these particular indexes and constraints?

- The ID columns are PKs and clustered indexes for hopefully obvious reasons; you use these for joins
- jobs.title_id is an FK for hopefully obvious data integrity reasons
- jobs.title_id is not null because every job should have a title
- jobs.title_id needs an index in order to speed up joins
- job_titles.title has an index because you've indicated you'll be querying based on this column (though I wouldn't query in such a fashion, especially since you've said there will be many titles; see below)
- job_titles.title has a unique constraint because there's no reason to have duplicates of the same title. You can (and will) have multiple jobs with the same title, but you don't need two entries for "CEO" in job_titles. Enforcing this uniqueness will preserve data integrity useful for reporting purposes (e.g. plot the productivity of IT's web division based on how many "web developer" jobs are filled)

Remarks:

> Job title is going to be used as part of an auto-complete field so I'll be using a query to fetch results.

As I mentioned before, use key-value pairs here. Fetch a list of them into memory in your app, and query that list for your autocomplete values. Then send the ID off to the DB for your actual SQL query. The queries will perform better that way; even with indexes, searching integers is generally quicker than searching strings.

[You've said that titles will be user created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171722/db-design-for-one-to-one-single-column-table/28187015#comment44712851_28171782). Put some input sanitation and validation process in place, because you don't want redundant entries like "WEB DEVELOPER", "web developer", "web  developer", etc. Validation should occur at both the application and DB levels; the unique constraint is part (but all) of this. [Prodigitalson's remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171722/db-design-for-one-to-one-single-column-table/28187015#comment44712757_28171722) about separate machine and display columns is related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: after getting the clarify

A table like this is enough - just add the `job_title_id` column as foreign key in the main  `member` table

> ```
> ---- "job_title" table ---- (store the job_title)
>  1. pk - job_title_id
>  2. unique - job_title_name <- index this
> ```

__ original answer __

You need to clarify what's the job_title going represent

- a person that hold this position?
- the division/department that has this position?
- A certain set of attributes? like Sales always has a commission
- or just a string of what was it called?

From what I read so far, you just need the "job_title" as some sort of dimension - make the id for it, make the string searchable - and that's it

example

```
---- "employee" table ---- (store employee info)
 1. pk - employee_id
 2. fk - job_title_id
 3. other attribute (contract_start_date, salary, sex, ... so on ...)

---- "job_title" table ---- (store the job_title)
 1. pk - job_title_id
 2. unique - job_title_name <- index this

---- "employee_job_title_history" table ---- (We can check the employee job history here)
 1. pk - employee_id
 2. pk - job_title_id
 3. pk - is_effective
 4. effective_date [edited: this need to be PK too - thanks to KM.]
```

I still think you need to provide us a use-case - that will greatly improve both of our understanding I believe

Comment: I don't like your natural key on the employee_job_title_history  table, it will fail you when you switch back and forth between the same job title.

Comment: Ahh.. yes - effective date need to be a key too, thanks bro! - or we can use an auto increment column as a surrogate key

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a few fixed job titles you might want to use an enum in our database.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html
If that's not supported by your version of mysql simply encode it with a numerical index and resolve it to a human readable form in your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however there will be 100's+, that are created by users, so I think enum probably isn't the right solution.